# Unity3D: AI follow player script for prefab enemy?

Tags: unity, physics, ai

So I am having an issue, I have an enemy prefab that is created when the new wave happens(think of Nazi Zombies from Call of Duty, same system) but every script I have found that deals with ai following player always involves a public transform variable. The issue is that the object I put in that variable in the inspector does not save with the prefab, rendering the script useless. Is there anyway I can get the enemy prefab when the enemy spawns to follow the player?

He is a script I tried and failed due to the issue:

```
    //The target player
public Transform player;
//In what time will the enemy complete the journey between its position and the players position
public float smoothTime = 10.0f;
//Vector3 used to store the velocity of the enemy
private Vector3 smoothVelocity = Vector3.zero;

private void Start()
{
}

//Call every frame
void Update()
{
    //Look at the player
    transform.LookAt(player);
    //Move the enemy towards the player with smoothdamp
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position, ref smoothVelocity, smoothTime)*Time.deltaTime;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way is to assign the tag "Player" to the player-character. The tag selector is in the Inspector just below the name input. You can then obtain a reference to that player with:

```
player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
```

When your player is already in the scene when the enemy is spawned, you can put that into `Start`. When the player might join the scene later or leave the scene to get replaced with another player object, you should do this in `Update` instead and handle the case that `FindWithTag("Player")` returns `null`.

Also keep in mind that when you have more than one game-object with the tag "Player" in the scene, you can't predict which one will be found by FindWithTag. If you want to allow multiple players, you should use `FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")` which returns an array of all player game objects and then implement a logic for choosing which player to engage.

Comment: Ahhh okay, thank you very much! I was trying to do something like this, just didn't add the .transform in the end of it haha